# Identify "correct" recoding pattern for classification

Tags: r

I am attempting to compare the results of clustering from an original data. In the original data, each individual is assigned to a ``class'', with the following frequencies for a 3-class data.

```
orig.class <- c(2672, 2672, 2672)
```

After clustering, the individuals are assigned to a class based on the results. However, the class labels generated are arbitrary. So I generated the different permutations for each of the 3-class combinations (i.e., 6). The frequencies of the classification results look like this:

```
permu1 <- c(2544, 2664, 2808)
permu2 <- c(2544, 2808, 2664)
permu3 <- c(2664, 2544, 2808)
permu4 <- c(2808, 2544, 2664)
permu5 <- c(2664, 2808, 2544)
permu6 <- c(2808, 2664, 2544)
```

By looking at each of the frequency tables, for example,

```
table(orig.class, permu1)
```

I can figure out which permutation (permu4) should be used for recoding, since my end goal is to compare how accurate the classification results are. But I can't figure out how to do this automatically in R.

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How do you infer that you need "permu4" since all `table(orig.class, permu_)` give the same output? Perhaps I'm stepping into unknown paths here, but -nonetheless- there should be someone who could help with a bit of clarification.

Comment: ''permu4'' is the one I need because that is the one with the highest match frequencies, when compared with the ``orig.class''

Answer (score 0):

I think computing the trace of the matrix would work. Looking at the frequency table,

```
table(orig.class, permu1)
```

I want the permutation with the highest match frequencies. To get this, I can compute the sum of the diagonals of the matrix.